# How to store every element of a cell array in a separate folders?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, directory, cell-array

I have a problem assigning and storing data to subfolders. I have one folder let's say a new folder, and I created 6 subfolders based on the size of a cell array. Now I want to save every element of the cell to subfolders in order but automatically. The following is my code and I was wondering how to make use of `for` loop to make it an automatic iteration. That is because it is going to be much more cell argument later for example 50 to 100.
Here is the code:

```
n = 1;
folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data1';
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n}, fileName);

folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data2';
n1=n+1;
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n1));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n1}, fileName);

folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data3';
n2=n1+1;
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n2));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n2}, fileName);

folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data4';
n3=n2+1;
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n3));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n3}, fileName);

folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data5';
n4=n3+1;
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n4));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n4}, fileName);

folder = 'C:\Users\HSH\Desktop\MATLABCOURSE\simulation_Data6';
n5=n4+1;
fileName = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png', n5));
imwrite( adj_level2{1,n5}, fileName);
```

More accurately, how to assign n to simulation_Data (name of subfolders)?

Comment: You can try  `for ii = 1:6; folder = spintf('C:\\Users\\simulation_Data%d', ii); filename = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png' ii); imwrite(adj_level2{1, ii}, filename); end`. This looks pretty straightforward. It looks like you are familiar with sprintf? Consider having a look at some introductory information on loops and string formatting in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number when reallocating `folder` the same way you do with `filename` - using `sprintf`:

```
for ii = 1:6 
    folder = spintf('C:\\Users\\HSH\\simulation_Data%d', ii); 
    filename = fullfile(folder, sprintf('image_%d.png' ii); 
    imwrite(adj_level2{1, ii}, filename); 
end
```

If you are doing this for numbers more than 9 or 99, you may want to consider using something like `pad(int2str(ii), 4, 'left', '0')` ([see `pad` here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pad.html)) to help ensure that the folders are indexed in numerical/alphabetical order - but this is cosmetic only.